# Javascript - Can someone please explain this code

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning to code in JavaScript and my assignment was to find out what each line of this code means. I've tried to figure out some of the code but the part which confuses me most is the functions,'div classes',document.createElement('something') and the append.Child('something').I have researched on the internet but it is vaguely explained. Please can someone explain each line of the code;here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Traffic lights</title>
</head>
<script>
var images = ['redlight.jpg', 'Red -yellow light.jpg', 'Green Light.jpg', 'Amber Light.jpg'];
var index = 0;

function buildImage() {
  var img = document.createElement('img')
  img.src = images[index];
  document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);
}

function changeImage() {
  var img = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
  index++;
  index = index % 4;
  img.src = images[index];
}
</script>

<body onload="buildImage();">
    <div class="contents" id="content"></div>
    <button onclick="setInterval(changeImage, 3000)">NextImage</button>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Let me see element it contain id = `content`. :)

Comment: _Please can someone explain each line of the code_ - Yes. _is it reasonable to think that someone will here at SO?_ Not in my opinion. Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/ - each of the functions you've mentioned by name are easily findable there and you can learn about each of them before you develop an understanding of how the functions and concepts tie together. You should ask tightly focussed questions when here.

Comment: `the functions 'div classes'` ... no such code ... `.I have researched on the internet but it is vaguely explained` you're looking at the wrong places then - that stuff is javascript+DOM 101

Answer (score 1):

First Part:

```
function buildImage() {
  var img = document.createElement('img')
  img.src = images[index];
  document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);
}
```

This function

1. first create dynamic html tag of image
2. Assign Image src/path that contained in the var images =
   `['redlight.jpg', 'Red -yellow light.jpg', 'Green Light.jpg', 'Amber
   Light.jpg'];`
3. first get html tag that has id name **content** then append it means
   to hold the previous and next images

Second Part:

```
function changeImage() {
  var img = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
  index++;
  index = index % 4;
  img.src = images[index];
}
```

This function

1. first initialize the img variable with the content/image that hold
   in **content** div by access through an array index Increment to
   access other image
2. using Modulus logic to get images that are on 4 index
3. Relace srcwith existing

Answer (score 1):

This code displays an image when the page is loaded, then changes the image every 3 seconds after the user clicked the button once. Here is how it works:

`buildImage` is a function that creates an `<img />` element (`document.createElement`) and set the source (`img.src`) attribute to one of the sources listed in the array `images`. Which one exactly depends on the `index` variable. It then adds the element to the html page, under the div with the id content (`getElementById('content').appendChild(img)`). So you end up with:

```
 <div class="contents" id="content">
     <img src="redlight.jpg" />
 </div>
```

The function is called only once, when the page is loaded (see the `onload` attribute).

`changeImage` changes the image source (`img.src`). the code

```
 document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
```

means "get the div with id = content, then find all the html tags "img" and return the first one".

the code

```
index++; index = index % 4;
```

increments the index variable, but ensure it is never more than 4 (the size of your array, see the modulo operator).

Finally, the `setInterval` is a function which takes a function name and a duration in milliseconds. Once called, it will run the function every X ms.

!!

In this code, the `setInterval` function is called on every click. It might be problematic. I would change it if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

`document.createElement('img')` creates a new `<img />` tag. `img.src = images[index]` takes the path of the first element inside `images` (because index is set to 0 at the beginning) and sets the source (='redlight.jpg'). With `document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img)` you add the created `<img src='redlight.jpg' />` tag inside your `<div>` with id = 'content'.

`div class='contents'` defines that your `div` is using the css class 'contents'. This css class handles the styling of your `div` element.

Answer (score 0):

There are really good explanation for this all at http://www.w3schools.com/. You should study that page.

For the parts that you are insecure about.

**Function**

Functions is a big subject itself. It's a huge part of about every programming language. It's a way to in an effective way do something that you might want to do more than one time. Lets say you want to make a function that subtracts two values, but you want to use it for any value. Then you can create a function that takes two parameters and do the calculation...

```
function sub(x, y)
{
  return x-y;
} // Very basic example
```

In that way you can send any values.

**document.createElement('img')**

Will simply just create an HTML-tag. In this case an 'img' tag. In your case they want to create one in order to place it inside another element.

**Div classes**(?) No idea what this is. Any examples?

**document.getElementById("something").append.Child('something2')**

What this will do is simply take an element by it's id. It can be a DIV or List etc. Then you simply put your element "something2" inside that element. So if something2 is an img, and something is a div. The result would be like:

```
<div>
  <img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Onload i.e when the page has being loaded it calls buildImage() function of javascript.This function creates a img tag and appends to the div which is of class 'contents'(Since index is 0 it loads a first image i.e img.src = images[index]).

And once you click on button every 3000 milliseconds its changes the image source to different image based on the index